# Spontaneous radiative decay due to electric dipole radiation

Tags: radiation, dipole

In my textbook, we calculated the rate at which an electric dipole radiates energy to be

$Pwr = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{2}{3c^3}\left(\frac{d^2 p}{dt^2} \right)^2$

where p is the dipole moment. Next it says that this result is similar to a nonrelativistic formula for the power radiated by a particle of charge q and acceleration a:

$Pwr = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{2q^2a^2}{3c^3}$

That's clear (replace $p$ by $qx$). Now we say that a free (=non-driven) oscillator "can be expected to convert its oscillation energy to radiation. If the radiative lifetime  of an oscillator obtained in this was is designated $\tau$, then $\frac{1}{\tau}$ is the radiation rate, and one finds

$\frac{1}{\tau} = \frac{1}{4\pi \epsilon_0}\frac{2e^2\omega_0^2}{3mc^3}$. "

Where does this come from? Is $\frac{1}{\tau}=Pwr$? If so, I would have replaced $a$ with the acceleration for a normal harmonic oscillator, which is $a=-\frac{k}{m}x$ which is clearly not consistent with the formula above.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We have that the power $P$ is energy/time. Thus to obtain the radiation rate (which is 1/time), we have to divide by an energy. The energy is the energy stored in the oscillator $U$ as the time to radiate this energy away is $\tau = U/P$.

Let us assume that the particle (with charge $e$) in the oscillator performs a motion of the form
$$ q= q_0 \cos(\omega_0 t)$$ with $q_0$ the amplitude of the oscillation.

The energy in the oscillator is $$U= \frac12 m \omega_0^2 q_0^2 $$ 
and the power (averaged over a cycle, i.e., over the time $1/\omega_0$)
$$ P = \frac12 \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{2 e^2 q_0^2\omega_0^2}{3 c^3} .$$
So we get the radiation rate
$$ \frac1\tau = \frac{P}{U} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon_0} \frac{2 e^2 \omega_0^2 }{3 mc^3}. $$

Comment: Isn't the energy in the oscillator $U=\frac{1}{2}mq_0^2\omega_0^2$? Furthermore, your radiation rate includes $q_0^2$ while the one I've given includes $\omega_0^2$

Comment: @SaschaFrölich: I have fixed that.

Comment: You're result for $\frac{1}{\tau}$ is still different from mine. Yours is $\propto q_0^2$ while the one given by my book is $\propto \omega_0^2$

Comment: Also fixed that.